# QApplication Execution Segmentation Fault Error

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

Can anybodyy help me with this. I am trying run an application using the cmakefiles. on the main file of my program I get a segmentation fault when the program gets to the line of code to execute the QAppication. Here is the fragment code below:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
bool viewing;
parse_command_line( argc, argv );

#ifdef _GRAPHICS_

  glutInit(&argc, argv);
#endif

 if( viewing )
        {
#ifdef _GRAPHICS_
      QApplication application(argc, argv);
      Viewer    *viewer = new Viewer( 0, exp, argc, argv );
      Interface *render = new Interface( 0, exp, viewer );
      render->show();
      return application.exec(); //this line causes the segmentation fault
      delete viewer;
      delete render;
#endif
        }


}
```

Comment: Is argc or argv somehow modified by parse_command_line() or glutInit() ? What if you try to remove those?

Comment: Btw, your delete statements after application.exec() are never called due to the return statement that quits the main function right there.

Comment: Include the stack trace please

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that the application object is destroyed prior to other objects that use it. You should leverage the C++ semantics to help you with that - and get rid of the abhorrent manual memory management while you're at it:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  bool viewing;
  parse_command_line( argc, argv );

#ifdef _GRAPHICS_
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
#endif

  if (viewing) {
#ifdef _GRAPHICS_
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Viewer viewer( 0, exp, argc, argv );
    Interface render( 0, exp, &viewer );
    render.show();
    return app.exec();
#endif
  }
}
```

The above is necessary - thus you must make the change to avoid undefined behavior. But the fix may not be sufficient if your `Viewer` or `Interface` implementations have bugs.